# How can I create a pdf list of all installed fonts?

Tags: bash, fonts

How can I list all installed fonts using a **custom example text** in a pdf file?

Something like [font-sampler](https://github.com/FontManager/master) does but more robust to errors in fonts (missing ttf names and others).

Comment: Does `pdffonts` (from package `poppler-utils`) like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/614694/6164712) do what you want?

Comment: no, pdffonts do  reverse thing. it lists the fonts in a document. I want to generate document.pdf containing custom text in all font variants. either for system fonts and for user specified fonts

Comment: Ah, now I get it – please [edit] your question to make that clear. Using `pdflatex` or maybe `lualatex` provides a solution, however I'm not quite sure it's an easy one…

Comment: Would a LaTeX solution be acceptable? Do you have LaTeX installed or, if not, are you open to installing it?